# Reading all observations from a csv file

Tags: r

i have imported this file into R only problem is there is 380 observations and it only reads first 100 observations. How can i get the rest of it, here it is
`BPL16_17 <- read.csv("BPL16:17.csv") 
BPL16_17`

Thanks

Comment: This is going to be difficult to answer without access to your dataset, but there is nothing wrong with your code

Comment: but how to i do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Asking a good question usually answers my problems 80% of the time. It is a difficult skill to develop and making mock code to simulate what you are doing is one of the best things to learn how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I always recommend using readr::read_csv over read.csv.

While I am unsure why read.csv is limited to 100 columns (This has not been true for many years now, my mistake) read_csv is not and handles data_frames much better especially dates, times and doesn't include factors by default.

https://github.com/tidyverse/readr

Also a great resource is this chapter from the *R for data science* book which is available online always for free.
http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-import.html

Comment: read.csv is not limited to 100 columns?

Comment: Maybe they changed that, but for years it was limited to less then 100 columns. Looks like read.csv has increased to 2067 columns width. Perhaps he is viewing the data set in RStudio and RStudio can limit the max width of a data frame that you can view to the first 100 columns?

Comment: perhaps, but the op mentions observations which i would normally equate with rows rather than columns - either way there is nothing obviously wrong with their code.

Comment: (ps : Seems you can have more than 2067 columns: `dat = matrix(rnorm(2100), nc=2100) ; dim(dat) ; write.csv(dat, temp<-tempfile()) ;
newdat = read.csv(temp, row.names=1) ; dim(newdat);`